# Spring Integration with JMS backed channels - "Dispatcher has no subscribers"

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I am a newbie to Spring Integration and am trying to execute a very basic Producer/Consumer application with SI and ActiveMQ.

I see messages being produced and stored on the queue, but when the Consumer ( service activator in this case) processes the message and tries returning a new message to the output channel, I keep getting below warning messages :

```
11:28:14.425 WARN [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1][org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageLis tenerContainer] Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryExc eption: Dispatcher has no subscribers for jms-channel jsonResponseChannel.
at org.springframework.integration.jms.SubscribableJm sChannel$DispatchingMessageListener.onMessage(Subs cribableJmsChannel.java:159)

Below is the snapshot of my context xmls :

common-context.xml
---------------------
..............
<bean id="requestQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
<constructor-arg value="INPUT_MSG_QUEUE" />
</bean>
<bean id="responseQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
<constructor-arg value="OUTPUT_MSG_QUEUE" />
</bean>
<int-jms:channel id="jsonGreetingRequests" queue-name="INPUT_MSG_QUEUE" message-driven="true"/>
<int-jms:channel id="jsonResponseChannel" queue-name="OUTPUT_MSG_QUEUE" message-driven="true"/>
<bean name="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFacto ry">
<property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>
..............

consumer-context.xml
---------------------
.............

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="newRequestsInChannelAdapter" destination="requestQueue" channel="jsonGreetingRequests"/>
<!-- <int-jms:inbound-gateway request-channel="jsonGreetingRequests" reply-channel="jsonResponseChannel" request-destination="requestQueue" />-->

<int:chain input-channel="jsonGreetingRequests" output-channel="jsonResponseChannel">
<int:json-to-object-transformer type="com.periscope.samples.service.Message"/>
<int:service-activator method="greetHello">
<bean class="com.periscope.samples.service.impl.HelloWor ldServiceImpl"/>
</int:service-activator>
<int:object-to-json-transformer />
</int:chain>

<stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="greetingsStdOut" channel="jsonResponseChannel"/>
.....................

producer-context.xml
-----------------------
.....
<int:gateway id="greetings"
default-request-channel="greetingRequests"
service-interface="com.periscope.samples.service.Greetings "/>
<int:channel id="greetingRequests"/>

<int:chain input-channel="greetingRequests" output-channel="jsonGreetingRequests">
<int:object-to-json-transformer />
</int:chain>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="jmsGreetingsOutChannelAdapter" channel="jsonGreetingRequests" destination="requestQueue"/>
.......
```

This is basically a msg string being wrapped in a user defined object and then sent on the INPUT_MSG_QUEUE. Consumer reads that msg , processes it and returns a new message on the OUTPUT_MSG_QUEUE. These are ActiveMQ backed channels and queues.

Can someone please throw some light as to how to get rid of these warnings since in this particular use case, I do not expect any other subscriber listening on the output_msg_queue ?

```
Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both jms channel adapters AND jms-backed queues.

With your current config you have two consumers on INPUT_MSG_QUEUE (the channel and the channel adapter).

jms-backed channels are really only needed for message persistence. For sending messages to a different application, use the adapters.

Simply change these

```
<int-jms:channel id="jsonGreetingRequests" queue-name="INPUT_MSG_QUEUE" message-   driven="true"/>
<int-jms:channel id="jsonResponseChannel" queue-name="OUTPUT_MSG_QUEUE" message-driven="true"/>
```

to simple `<int:channel/>`s.

Also, given that you are using request/response semantics, starting with a `<gateway/>` you need to use jms in/out gateways, not adapters (which are for one-way integration).